# How to allow inserting on DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am binding a `DataGridView` from a `List<T>`. I have set on the designer `Enable adding`.

If the list is null I am creating an empty list so the headers are shown, but it is not creating an empty line for me to be able to add elements. Why? How can I enable the user to add values to this list?

Some code

```
public IEnumerable<Value> ValueList
{
    get;
    set;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    if (ValueList == null)
    {
        ValueList = new List<Value>();
    }

    dataGrid.DataSource = ValueList;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you binding on a `BindingList`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx

Comment: @Jon I didn't know about `BindingList`, I don't usually code on winforms. Changing it to a `BindingList` worked, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, [`DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) must be `true` (and it is since you are setting it in the designer).

That property says

> If the DataGridView is bound to data,
>   the user is allowed to add rows if
>   both this property and the data
>   source's IBindingList.AllowNew
>   property are set to true.

[`IBindingList.AllowNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.allownew.aspx) (which is not settable) also mentions:

> If IList.IsFixedSize or
>   IList.IsReadOnly is true, this
>   property returns false.

Since you are binding to an `IEnumerable`, I believe `IsReadOnly` is `false`. Try exposing the list as a `List<T>` and binding to a `BindingList<T>`.

```
public List<Value> ValueList
{
    get;
    set;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    if (ValueList == null)
    {
        ValueList = new List<Value>();
    }

    dataGrid.DataSource = new BindingList<Value>(ValueList);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That property will be false if you have DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true; but do not have default constructor for your binding class.
Add default and it should work

```
public class atsTableInclude
{
    // keep this to allow user to add row
    public atsTableInclude() { }

    public atsTableInclude(string p, bool u)
    {
        Prefix = p;
        Use = u;
    }

    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public bool Use { get; set; }
}

    public Sorting.SortableBindingList<T> FillAtsList<T>(string jsonfile) where T : class
    {
        if (!File.Exists(jsonfile))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(jsonfile, "File not found");
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            // load json from file
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonfile))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
                return new Sorting.SortableBindingList<T>(res);                   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Cannot load json", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return null;
    }
    private void frmATS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        string jsonfile2 = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "atsTableInclude.json");
        dataGridView2.DataSource = FillAtsList<atsTableInclude>(jsonfile2);
    }
```

Comment: Adding a default constructor did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jon's answer: `BindingList<T>` has an event, `AddingRow`, which you can listen to, to specifiy the item to be added:

```
AddHandler _bindingList.AddingNew, Sub(s, args)
                                           args.NewObject = New TicketItem("dawg")
                                       End Sub
```